# How to enforce python file naming convention (e. g. snake_case) for all files in a python project?

Tags: python, lint

I would like to ensure that all the files in my **Python** project follow snake_case **naming convention**.

(Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/308972/python-file-naming-convention )

For **JavaScript** projects I already use **eslint** rules. However, I did not find corresponding rules for Python and pylint.

For pylint I only found

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/warning/non-ascii-file-name.html

and in the following question only naming conventions inside files seem to be considered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220580/change-default-python-coding-style

=> How to enforce a naming convention for the files?

**Related resources**

**A.** **Eslint-Rules (JavaScript)**

"folders/match-regex"

"filenames/match-regex"

(Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74405952/what-are-recommented-folder-and-file-naming-conventions-eslint-settings-for-ne)

**B.** **pre-commit** hooks

Unfortunately, git pre-commit hooks cannnot be automtically activated/included under version control and I did not find a pre-commit hook to check file naming conventions.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703159/git-remote-shared-pre-commit-hook/3703207#3703207

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649628/how-can-i-add-my-pre-commit-hook-to-an-existing-git-repository

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204155/how-to-version-the-git-config-file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462955/putting-git-hooks-into-a-repository

**C. GitLab pipline**

I did not find an example for a GitLab pipeline enforcing a naming style.

**D. Regular expressions**

Here is some python code to check file name patterns:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665468/test-whether-a-file-name-has-the-correct-naming-convention-in-python

**E. Pytlnt issue**

https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/8569

**F. Apply Pylint to non .*.py files**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436538/how-to-use-pylint-for-all-the-files-with-non-py-extension-in-a-directory-for-win

Answer (score 1):

You could use popular [flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) with this [flake8-filename](https://pypi.org/project/flake8-filename/) plugin. It allows checking for basically any format(s) that match defined regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that pylint does have a checker for module/file names:
the [invalid-name](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html) checker.

That rule can be applied to *.py files.

I did not find a way to apply it to other files (*.txt, *.xlsx), yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some custom python solution that checks all folders and files to be snake_case:

(File names with double underscore like "mapping__foo_baa__to__qux.xlsx" are allowed)

```
import os
import re


def main():
    directory_to_check = "."
    folders_to_exclude = ['.pytest_cache', '.vscode']
    check_folders_and_files_to_be_in_snake_case(
        directory_to_check,
        folders_to_exclude
    )


def check_folders_and_files_to_be_in_snake_case(
    directory_to_check,
    folders_to_exclude
):
    for path, sub_folders, files in os.walk(directory_to_check):
        for sub_folder in sub_folders:
            if sub_folder in folders_to_exclude:
                continue
            else:
                check_snake_case(path, sub_folder)

        if is_excluded_path(path, folders_to_exclude):
            continue
        else:
            for name in files:
                check_snake_case(path, name)


def is_excluded_path(path, folders_to_exclude):
    for folder_to_exclude in folders_to_exclude:
        if path.endswith(folder_to_exclude):
            return True
    return False


def check_snake_case(path, name):
    if not is_snake_case(name):
        message = "Directory or file name is not in snake_case:\n" + path + '/' + name
        raise Exception(message)


def is_snake_case(name):
    items = name.split('.')
    name_without_ending = items[0]
    if name_without_ending == '':
        return True

    _rex = re.compile("[a-z0-9]+(?:_+[a-z0-9]+)*")
    is_snake = _rex.fullmatch(name_without_ending)
    if not is_snake:
        foo = 1
    return is_snake


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```